# ASP.NET application hangs after Page_Load - seems to be worker process specific?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

#### The Problem

I have an ASP.NET web application connecting to an SQL server database.

Occasionally, the application hangs when some specific *users* try to log in. I can replicate this when I try to log in as that user on the live site from my machine, but the problem doesn't appear in an identical site (the same code, the same machine, the same database and user account - only the worker process and application pool are different).

The problem also disappears (at least temporarily) on an application pool recycle. When it happens again it tends to be the same users.

Normally I'd assume this was a problem in the application-specific code or database, and I'm still looking for a way that that's possible, but the fact it doesn't happen in an identical site running against the same database makes me doubt it.

#### More information

From some logging, the hang seems to happen after the Page_Load of the requested page, but before the Page_Load of the user controls on that page.

The hanging requests can be seen in the current requests of the site's worker process in IIS, the state shows as ExecuteRequestHandler and the module is the IsapiModule.

The SQL server's activity monitor shows no long running queries during the time that the application is hanging, the profiler shows no frequent identical queries coming from the application during the hang.

Most users can continue to use the application without problems.

The application stores user details with the in process ASP.NET session state.

On some occasions the problem has disappeared on its own after 10-20 minutes, other times it persists until an application pool recycle.

Occasionally the logging shows that after ~5 minutes of hanging after the requested page's Page_Load, the Page_Load of the first child user control is called, after which there is another hang.

#### Summary

I'm basically wondering if there is any chance that this might be due to a problem with ASP.NET session locking (are there any known bugs, or dangers of deadlock on session?)

Could it be a problem with the request's thread being assigned a low priority for processor time?

If anybody has any ideas about what this could be I'd be interested, if not, then might debugging a memory dump of the worker process help me? I don't have any experience of or know anything about how safe it is to take a memory dump of a live, running worker process.

Comment: If the app is hanging out for certain users only, then it is most likely to be the data issue. In that case, the data coming from db SP's may be taking plenty of time. You should try to profile the SP calls for the particular set of users. Also on the app side in the usercontrols, you should set the contorl directive to AutoEventWireUp=false and manually set the event handler delegates in the OnInit event handler. In most cases, it is SP code which is a culprit and takes ages to return the data to the app.

Comment: Hi, thanks. My first thought was that it was a stored procedure/data access problem as well, but the database activity monitor and profiler show no unusually long running queries, and the problem cannot be recreated on an identical site running against the same data.

Comment: Just as a thought, have you tried re-creating the application pool that the live site is running on? I appreciate that this may cause unwanted downtime but maybe you have pre-set maintenance slots?

Comment: Please share some code from your project to look into it.

Comment: @Karan the problem seems to happen outside of the application-specific code, between the parent Page_Load and the child controls Page_Load, so there is no specific code. Also, identical code doesn't suffer the problem under another worker process.

Comment: @Sean Thanks, I liked the idea, we did that this morning so we'll see how it goes. Was there any reasoning behind it, e.g. are old app pools known to be vulnerable to corruption in some way outside of the config, or was it just a suggestion based on the identical working site I described?

Comment: @beeneto not in any way that I can explain, I've had some very weird occurrences where IIS just refuses to play ball for no apparent reason and simply re-creating things works for me. The fact that an identical set of code works could also indicate that there is an error or a missed change somewhere in the config.